# dataframe if string contains substring divide by 1000

Tags: python, dataframe, contains

I have this dataframe looking like the below dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['yellow', '800test' ], ['red','900ui'], ['blue','900test'], ['indigo','700test'], ['black','400ui']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Donor', 'value'])
```

In the value field, if a string contains say 'test', I'd like to divide these numbers by 1000. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, 'these numbers' is referring to the number in the string? And after dividing by 1000, the string will still have the word `test`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below code using **lambda** function

```
df['value_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(int(x.value.replace('test',''))/1000)+'test' if x.value.find('test') > -1 else x.value, axis=1)
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As per @RAHUL MAURYA's answer, the code will crash if the testcase has the word "test" in the body yet not all of letters in body are equal to "test".

Answer (score 0):

```
df["value\d"] = df.value.str.findall("\d+").str[0].astype(int)
df["value\w"] = df.value.str.findall("[^\d]+").str[0]
df.loc[df["value\w"] == "test", "value\d"]  = df["value\d"]/1000
df["value"] = df["value\w"] + df["value\d"].astype(str)
```